# Create a feature in open atrium of Drupal

Tags: drupal

i am new in open atrium of Drupal and i got the documentation of how to add a feature form the link https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/449#an-imageboard-feature. But here i cant know how a feature add from scratch as per the users requirements . Is there any step by step instruction of creating the custom feature in open atrium of Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way of building a Feature - which is the one it is explained in the tutorial you read - is to work things out in Drupal/OpenAtrium Administration.
When all is ready, you export the Feature, then you have a folder which you can use in any site just as if it were a Module.